# magento with M2E Pro ReferenceError: ListingProductAddObj is not defined

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, extensions, configuration, m2epro

[image]

I use M2E Pro with Magento 2.3.4 clear installation
When I'm trying set config in M2E Pro I got an error in console.
Have somebody the same error? is it a problem with extension or with Magento?